# Eclipse library path error after moving project to git repository

Tags: android, eclipse, path

Im trying to get myself to github. After I moved the project into a local repository, there an error occured in libraries paths, it seems that they are remembering the former path in my workspace? Any ideas? It says that library is missing, but it actually is in the project's folder.
Any help appreciated.
THere is a screenshot:
[library error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhY5l.jpg)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. It seems to be a bug in File->Move when applied to a project. It doesn't move the library references correctly. Even after I manually re-added the libraries, the old incorrect addresses remained. So although my files themselves have no errors, the "missing" library references remain, and are viewable but not removable in the Build Path dialog. I'll see what else I can figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when **your library is project with source** and not jar:

1. Right click on project dir - Properties
2. Choose Android on left side
3. In a lower "Library" section will be reference to old library with red cross
4. remove it
5. add library from new location
6. enjoy

when **your library is jar**:

1. Right click on project dir - Properties
2. Choose Java build Path on left side
3. Choose Libraries tab
4. remove old libraries
5. add new external jars from your location
6. enjoy

or:

do steps 1-4 and then:

1. copy your jar library to libs dir of android project
2. right click on newly copied jar in libs
3. choose build path -> add to build path from menu
4. enjoy

Hope it helps you and somebody else ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question to be helpful: [Cannot Add Library to Android Project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018977/cannot-add-library-to-android-project-in-eclipse).

It wasn't enough to add the libraries back in manually. Doing Project->(right click) Properties->Android->Add and then adding the library made it work (#4 in answer I linked).

Update: on a couple of other projects I tried this with, I also needed to close the project [(right-click)->Close Project], and re-open it (double-click). Then I tried to run it; it failed once; then worked.

To sum up, this is what worked for me the most reliably:

1) Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Jar to add my libraries

2) Properties->Android->Add to add them again for real somehow

3) Close and reopen project

4) Attempt to run; fail; errors go away; run again. Success.

Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that restarting the Eclipse IDE often fixes referential issues after moving into git repo.

I generally use Android Private Library folder for external jars, and you cannot remove/add these like directly referenced libraries.