# Can't import project with "android-support-v7-appcompat which resolves" error

Tags: android

I can't import this project

https://www.dropbox.com/s/182zpz7acu5opyo/com.resulam.android.NufiTchamna_nufi_francais_nufi_prototype.zipp.rar?dl=0

this is the full error

> Project
>   com.resulam.android.NufiTchamna_nufi_francais_nufi:C:\Users\gaewgan\Desktop\dic\dics\project.properties:
>   Library reference ..\android-support-v7-appcompat could not be found
>   Path is
>   C:\Users\gaewgan\Desktop\dic\dics..\android-support-v7-appcompat
>   which resolves to
>   C:\Users\gaewgan\Desktop\dic\android-support-v7-appcompat

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the appcompat-v7 library project which you have to import as well into your workspace on top of your existing project. For more information refer to these existing guides:

1. For Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library
2. For Eclipse: [Cannot Add Library to Android Project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018977/cannot-add-library-to-android-project-in-eclipse)